# DOM Table Add Row - need to require Picklist Selection

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I have been using the code on the following link for quite sometime and it works great however I now have a need to require a picklist selection from the list of values. My current picklist works fine so it is the "require" capability that I need help with:

http://www.mredkj.com/tutorials/tableaddrow.html

Can someone point me in the right direction? Thanks.

CG

Answer (score 0):

It was not my intention to answer my own question but in case someone else stumbles across this post in the future the solution was simple but took a bit of trial and error.

Simply add the following line to the **// select cell** section:

```
sel.required = true;
```

Also make sure the first option contains no text in between the second set of single quotes

```
sel.options[0] = new Option('-SELECT-', '');
```